Snowflake query issue with hung state
I have an engine that runs multiple queries on snowflake (ETL). Sometimes one of the queries get hung and takes so long to run. But when I check at snowflake, the query is already complete.
Can someone help finding what could be happening?
I'm using python snowflake connector.
Here is the sample code I connect snowflake and fetch.
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user=self.user,
        password=self.password,
        account=self.account,
        warehouse=self.warehouse,
        database=self.database,
        schema=self.schema,
        insecure_mode=True,
    )

    cs = ctx.cursor()
    cs.execute(query)
    response = cursor.fetchallarrow(
        strings_as_dictionary=strings_as_dictionary,
        adaptive_integers=adaptive_integers,
    )

  if return_pandas:
      df = response.to_pandas()
      df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)
      df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
      return df


Where are you executing this code? It's always the same query hung, or randomly one of them?

Have you tried debugging to see which line of the code hang's for a long time

Mostly random query gets hung

@Aravindanvaithialingam, yes, I have put logger after te execute but that is not getting printed
